# How to change color of navigation bar?

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller

I put a navigation bar but I don't know how to change color of it, I tried to do it in Main.storyboard but it's not working, then I tried to do it with code but I don't know how to do it exactly.
Can someone help me how to do it ?

Comment: Show your code and it will be more likely you get a useful answer

Comment: Ya, I got my answer, thanks. :)

Answer (score 7):

With code:

```
navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
```

With storyboard make sure to select Navigation Bar in the Document Outline, then show the Attributes Inspector in the Utilities (right window in Xcode):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

for objective c, i can tell:
you need to use barTintColor of the UINavigationBar of the UINavigationController object you created
use something like:

`UINavigationController *nav = [.....
[[nav navigationBar] setBarTintColor:[UIColor greyColor]];`